# Oracle SQLLDR Discard rows using WHEN clause not working

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I am trying to load a text file, only those rows where 3rd column 'c_nbr' Doesn't END with 'ABCD'. Since WHEN clause is really primitive I could not use, trim/substring with it.

My second choice was to put the last 4 chars of c_nbr field to a column called 'MSGCOL' and use that column in my WHEN clause, like " WHEN MSGCOL  <> 'ABCD' ".

The MSGCOL is getting value "ABCD" where column 'c_nbr' ends with "ABCD", but the WHEN clause is not DISCARDing them.

Why it's not working? How can I achieve my goal? Can I run SQL Query from sqlldr control file itself? Like "Delete from tbl_load where c_nbr like '%ABCD';" at the end of loading commands?

SQLLDR Control File:-

```
OPTIONS (ERRORS=9999)
LOAD DATA

INFILE '052140.csv'
BADFILE '052140.BAD'
DISCARDFILE '052140.DIS'

INFILE '055913.csv'
BADFILE '055913.BAD'
DISCARDFILE '055913.DIS'

APPEND INTO TABLE tbl_load
WHEN MSGCOL  <> 'ABCD'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' optionally enclosed by '"' trailing nullcols 
(
id "TRIM(UPPER(:ID))",
pid,
c_nbr "TRIM(:c_nbr)",
a_nbr "SUBSTR(TRIM(:a_nbr), 1, 25)",
P_REASON2 FILLER,
MSGCOL EXPRESSION "substr(trim(:c_nbr), length(trim(:c_nbr))-3, 4)"
)
```

Comment: what if you use  `RTRIM` not `TRIM`?

Comment: to Benoit :: It will be same result. What I think happening is, the WHEN clause is really PREMITIVE and it only works on the PHYSICAL columns of the source file. Since I am using a calculated field, WHEN is not working. WHEN probably works before loading the data to the memory or to a stageing place, where as the calculated field is created after the row/physical fields already loaded to the memory/staging place. WHEN alays finds BLANK in the Calculated field, thus it does not work - in my opinion.